# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function (async)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am trying to execute the following function using async/await, but I getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Using the following code:

```
async function getCsrfToken() {
    let token = '';
    await $.get(domain + '/mobile/token', result => {
        token = result;
    });
    return token;
}
```

My Editor isn't complaining about the syntax, but Chrome within Crosswalk is complaining about it. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to do something within crosswalk?

Comment: You do know this feature is in a draft stage of ES6?

Comment: Really? I thought that it has been released... I have written this in TypeScript which is then compiled to ES6, although I have no idea what the TS compiled output looks like. I just assumed it was ready...

Comment: There are many transpilers, such as babeljs, that take ES6/7 code and transform it into modern JS. Try looking into it :)

Comment: Looks like it is in chrome 55 acording to this: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5643236399906816